# Kinect + Windows + OpenNI +OpenCV (Finger Detection)

Tags: kinect, kinect-sdk, ofxkinect

I have a question with Kinect. I am trying to run the code from [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lCuItHQEgEQ&feature=player_embedded#)!, the code is under the video the second one with OpenNI.

The problem is I have Windows and OpenNI and this code runs on Linux. I can't convert it to Windows. Do you know how? Or if there is another code on windows for finger detection?

When I run this I get errors such as:

> (unsigned int no variable declared as =)
>   unsigned short near = depth - 100; // near clipping plane

Note I tried to run the first code for Windows but it needs the CL NUI which I didn't install as I prefer OpenNI.